# Search, Threading and MySQL on android

Tags: android, mysql, multithreading

I'm trying to do a search from my database here is the code it keeps bringing the error below.The data is on a MySQL problem is it keeps crashing can somebody help me please.Here is my code.

```
public class Main extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Context ctx = this;
    private Context ctx2 = this;
    private ProgressDialog pd, pd2 = null;
    private Object data, data2 = null;private String url;private MapView myMap;
    private Connector http;

    static String searchy;
    String selection;
    // MapView mapView;
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    Drawable drawable;
    Drawable drawable2;
    CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedOverlay;
    CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem> itemizedOverlay2;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        myMap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        // addmarkers();
        // EditText searchInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
        // final String searchitem = searchInput.getText().toString().trim();

        Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Log.i("MyApp", "Background thread starting");

                // pd = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "Working..",
                // "Downloading Data...", true, false);

                addmarkers();
            }
        });

    }
```

//adds the searched markers to the map

```
 public void addmarkers() {
        url = "http://10.0.2.2/therm/searchy.php";
        http = new Connector(ctx);
        http.connect(url, myMap);  }
```

//class connector that adds overlays and fetches from the database

```
       public class Connector {
            private Drawable marker;
        private GeoPoint point;
        private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

        public Connector(Context ctx1) {
            ctx = ctx1;
            marker = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_marker);
            itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem>(
                    marker, myMap);
        }

        public void connect(String url, MapView myMap) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputStream is = null;
            // mapOverlays = myMap.getOverlays();
            // mapOverlays.clear();
            String result = null;
            int ct_id;
            String ct_name = null;
            // String[] ct_namey = null;
            String ct_add = null;
            String ct_lat;
            String ct_long;
            String imageURL;
            // the year data to send
            EditText txt_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
            String woi = txt_username.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), woi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("searchy", woi));
            // http post
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }

            // convert response to string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    Log.v("log_tag", "Line reads: " + line);

                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            // parse json data
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","address: " + json_data.getString("address")

                    );
                    if (searchy.equals(json_data.getString("address"))) {
                        ct_id = json_data.getInt("id");
                        ct_name = json_data.getString("name");
                        // ct_namey[i] = json_data.getString("name");
                        ct_add = json_data.getString("address");
                        ct_lat = json_data.getString("lat");
                        ct_long = json_data.getString("lng");
                        imageURL = json_data.getString("imageUrl");

                        Double lon = (Double.parseDouble(ct_long));
                        Double lat = (Double.parseDouble(ct_lat));

                        point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6),
                                (int) (lon * 1E6));

                        CustomOverlayItem overlayItem = new CustomOverlayItem(
                                point, ct_name, ct_add, imageURL);
                        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
                        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
                        myMap.postInvalidate();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                "No such address is found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            return;
        }

    }



    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

// the .php file

```
    <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("hospitals");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hosi WHERE address like '%".$_REQUEST['searchy']."%'");
    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();?>
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
//error04-06 16:04:07.162: V/log_tag(10708): Line reads: [{"id":"1","name":"The Nairobi Hospital","address":"Upperhill","consult":"2000","phone":"+254202846000","desc":"The.... "}]
04-06 16:04:07.162: V/log_tag(10708): Line reads: 
04-06 16:04:07.502: I/log_tag(10708): address: Upperhill
04-06 16:04:07.552: W/dalvikvm(10708): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400287f0)
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708): at   com.realestatefinder.plotjson.Main$Connector.connect(Main.java:276)
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708):    at com.realestatefinder.plotjson.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:86)
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 16:04:07.572: E/AndroidRuntime(10708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
```

Comment: What error are you getting.  Please edit your question and provide it.

Comment: i have updated the code please have a look at it

Comment: Which line is 276 in `Main`?  Have you debugged this code to see which of the objects on that line are `null`?

Comment: yes i have the error is on this line mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are getting a NPE because you've failed to initialize your `mapOverlays` collection.  You commented out the initialization:

```
 // mapOverlays = myMap.getOverlays();
 // mapOverlays.clear();
```

Your error shows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at   com.realestatefinder.plotjson.Main$Connector.connect(Main.java:276)
```

and you said that line 276 is:

```
   mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

I think you learn how to use the Android debugger so you can trace this sort of code in the future.  Best of luck.